# Can we use simple injector for dependency injection in wcf services and How?

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, simple-injector

Can we use simple injector for dependency injection in wcf services

Comment: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wcfintegration.html

Answer (score 1):

We can use simple injector for dependency injection in wcf services.Here is my demo.
After installing this NuGet package, it must be initialized in the start-up path of the application by calling the SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory.SetContainer method:

```
     protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var container = new Container();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

        container.RegisterWcfServices(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());


        container.Register<IDemo, Demo>();

        SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory.SetContainer(container);
    }
```

For each service class, you should supply a factory attribute in the .SVC file of each service class. For instance:

```
    <%@ ServiceHost
Service="Demo_rest_IIS.Service1"
CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs"
Factory="SimpleInjector.Integration.Wcf.SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory,
    SimpleInjector.Integration.Wcf"%>
```

Inject service through construction method:

```
     public class Service1 : IService1
     {
       private IDemo demo;
       public Service1(IDemo demo){
        this.demo = demo;
        }
     }
```

You can refer to the link below:

https://github.com/simpleinjector/Documentation/blob/master/source/wcfintegration.rst