# Consume wcf service in .net core which to use services.AddSingleton or services.AddTransient

Tags: wcf, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I am consuming a WCF service in my `.net core` API project and I used the following steps:

The binding in WCF service (for testing) `<add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />`

1. Created a proxy class using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x 
   (This created a proxy which has an interface `IService1` and calls `Service1Client`).
2. In the startup class I have bound the interface with the class `services.AddSingleton<IService1, Service1Client>();`

The method endpoint in the WCF service gets the data form the database according to the parameter passed to consume the WCF service.

I am not sure which one I should use, `services.AddSingleton` or `services.AddTransient`, because I am not sure what the proxy class is using to call the method.

If I create a single instance, will it be locked?

I have done a `Jmeter test` with 1000 rows in the database and 1000 rows from csv as a parameter to consume the API, but did not find any lock and all were successful under 3 minutes.

Comment: @DingPeng I am not sure about the WCF client working I came to know that it's thread safe so single instance is enough to handle all the request. I am not sure about DNS cashing and in case of not availability (for a second) of WCF service will it retry etc.

Comment: `services.AddSingleton<IService1, Service1Client>();` is working for me since long. And also observed if there was some issue at service end when it is resolved. It started working without recycling pool.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the servicereference.cs file to see which method in the wcf service is called by the proxy class.

[image]

Then we need to instantiate the proxy class and call the WCF service through the instantiated proxy class:

```
ServiceReference.Service1Client service1 = new Service1Client();
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your support. I know I can call method from service1 object. How do you inject this class into your core api is my question.

Comment: You can refer to this link, which contains how to use dependency injection in WCF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61723357/can-we-use-simple-injector-for-dependency-injection-in-wcf-services-and-how/61810429#61810429

Answer (score 1):

By this documentation in a web api a single httpclient should be instantiated:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient

Of course if you have multiple target services, with different endpoints, an HttpClient per service is needed (you set the base address in the HttpClient)

In your case your generated client should use an HttpClient under the covers. If you can determine if the whole genrated client is thread safe then you can inject the client as a Singleton, if not you should add it as scoped

Comment: Can you provide some reference in support of this statement **generated client should use an HttpClient under the covers**

Comment: Not really, I am supposing it because of the https binding, you should inspect the code of the generated client, as well it's thread safety, wich actually is the main point. Regardles the technology underneath, your decision of injecting as scoped or as singleton depends on the thread safety of the client